OpenVPN cluster crashes for missing attribute in ClusterDB
I have a openvpn installation. I joined a cluster through CLI.
./sacli --mysql mysql://${user}:${password}@${endpoint} ClusterJoin

The command finishes without errors. I checked and my user has the same password as the cluster, so everything went good.
But then when I try to query the ClusterStatus:
root@ip-10-90-2-194:/usr/local/openvpn_as/scripts# ./sacli ClusterNodesStatus
ERROR: AttributeError: 'ClusterDB' object has no attribute 'dbs' (9000)

This is a problem, because I am unable to access to the Admin Panel UI because this error (the web UI crashes).
What's the cause of this problem?
